# MediaPlayer is not playing some audio files from the server

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to implement an online devotional psalm streaming Android app. I am trying to stream these audio files from my website server directly using the `MediaPlayer` class provided by Android SDK framework.

Here is the code for my MediaPlaybackUtility.java

```
public class MediaPlaybackUtility {
    static boolean isMediaPlaying = false;
    static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    static void playPauseBhajan(String fileURL) {
        if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
           try {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(ONLINE_AUDIO_URL);
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        isMediaPlaying = true;
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            isMediaPlaying = false;
        }
    }

    static void stopBhajan() {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        isMediaPlaying = false;
    }
}
```

I entered the URL of the audio file saved on my server in the place of ONLINE_AUDIO_URL but there are some bizarre experiences I had while I was working with `MediaPlayer` class. The MediaPlayer class is playing some files while it is not playing others and I am not able to understand where the problem is.

Here are the links to the audio files that the above code is playing without any errors:

1. [testsong_20sec.mp3](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/testsong_20sec.mp3)

2. [TheRadiance.m4a](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/TheRadiance.m4a)

3. [WaitingfortheEnd.m4a](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/WaitingfortheEnd.m4a)

And here are the links that the MediaPlayer is not able to play:

1. [ShapeofYou.mp3](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/ShapeofYou.mp3)

2. [AreyDwalPalon.mp3](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/AreyDwarPalon.mp3)

3. [KrishnaTheme.mp3](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/KrishnaTheme.mp3)

4. [BataoKahaMilegaShyam.mp3](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/BataoKahaMilegaShyam.mp3)

I then tried to set a OnErrorListener to the MediaPlayer so that if there is some error streaming these files I could log these errors out and therefore I added these lines just after the `mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();` but then again when I changed the URL to one of those that the MediaPlayer was not able to play no errors were logged in the Logcat.

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e("MEDIAPLAYER", "Can't play media.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then I converted these MP3 files into M4A format just like this one
[AreyDwarPalonm4a.m4a](http://www.aayushgoyal.in/bhajansandhya/krishna/AreyDwarPalonm4a.m4a) but again no luck and still this file was not played by MediaPlayer from the server.

I have also searched the web and everywhere but couldn't find anything related to my specific problem. Maybe I am ignoring some fundamental concept here as I am working first time with MediaPlayer and audio files but again the main confusing part is, it is playing some of those files saved on the server but not the others.

Comment: Give `ExoPlayer` a try? It's supposed to support more codecs. 

https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Comment: Yeah did that and it worked. ExoPlayer is indeed a life savior. Thanks, @KartikArora. For people having same trouble or any trouble related to streaming media online refer https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to add this listener before mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync() like

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e("MEDIAPLAYER", "Can't play media.");
        return false;
    }
});
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah did that. Nothing happened. No errors logged and no media playback. Also this time I noted that while the audio file did not play, the internet connection speed increased drastically. Maybe something's happening as far as the audio file fetching is concerned but I don't know why the files are not played.

Comment: What about exo player it is an extensible media player for Android and support many more codecs [https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Answer (score -1):

It shows error while playing large audio file (>1mb).
Find some workaround for playing large file.
Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).